# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.DSACryptoServiceProvider' to type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSA'

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, token, saml

I am trying to get saml token by passing certificate authentication following this article
[How to pass a certificate to WSTrust to get Saml Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26750788/how-to-pass-a-certificate-to-wstrust-to-get-saml-token)

I am getting following error when I make a call like this

```
var token = factory.CreateChannel().Issue(rst) as GenericXmlSecurityToken;
```

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Security.Cryptography.DSACryptoServiceProvider' to type
>   'System.Security.Cryptography.RSA'

I tried cryptoconfig solution mentioned in this article 
https://dusted.codes/how-to-use-rsa-in-dotnet-rsacryptoserviceprovider-vs-rsacng-and-good-practise-patterns

It didn't solve the problem

Here is the complete stack trace

```
Server stack trace: 
 at System.Security.Cryptography.RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter.SetKey(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
at System.Security.Cryptography.SignatureDescription.CreateFormatter(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
at System.Security.Cryptography.RSAPKCS1SignatureDescription.CreateFormatter(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509AsymmetricSecurityKey.GetSignatureFormatter(String algorithm)
at System.IdentityModel.SignedXml.ComputeSignature(SecurityKey signingKey)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.WSSecurityOneDotZeroSendSecurityHeader.CompletePrimarySignatureCore(SendSecurityHeaderElement[] signatureConfirmations, SecurityToken[] signedEndorsingTokens, SecurityToken[] signedTokens, SendSecurityHeaderElement[] basicTokens, Boolean isPrimarySignature)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.WSSecurityOneDotZeroSendSecurityHeader.CreateSupportingSignature(SecurityToken token, SecurityKeyIdentifier identifier)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.SendSecurityHeader.SignWithSupportingToken(SecurityToken token, SecurityKeyIdentifierClause identifierClause)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.SendSecurityHeader.SignWithSupportingTokens()
at System.ServiceModel.Security.SendSecurityHeader.CompleteSecurityApplication()
at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAppliedMessage.OnWriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageWriter.WriteMessage(Message message, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 initialOffset, Int32 maxSizeQuota)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.SerializeBufferedMessage(Message message, Boolean shouldRecycleBuffer)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.SendRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.IWSTrustContract.Issue(Message message)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst, RequestSecurityTokenResponse& rstr)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst)
at TestClient.Program.GetSamlToken()
```

Here is the code

```
private static string GetSamlToken()
    {
        "Requesting identity token".ConsoleYellow();
        var stsBinding = new WS2007HttpBinding();
        stsBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
        stsBinding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
        stsBinding.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = false;
        stsBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate; 

        var factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(
           stsBinding,
           "https://sometestservice.com/service");
        factory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;
        factory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.LocalMachine, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.My,
            System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "<cert_thumbprint_removed>");


        var rst = new RequestSecurityToken
        {
            RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue,
            KeyType = KeyTypes.Bearer,
            TokenType = TokenTypes.Saml2TokenProfile11,
            AppliesTo = new EndpointReference("urn:webapisecurity")
        };

        var token = factory.CreateChannel().Issue(rst) as GenericXmlSecurityToken;
        return token.TokenXml.OuterXml;
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: who ever downvoted, care to explain why?

Comment: Not really an answer but what version of .NET are you using because what you are using has been deprecated as stated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.protocols.wstrust.wstrustchannelfactory.aspx).

Comment: my application is in .net 4.6.1

Answer (score 1):

Just goes to show the amount of legacy assumptions in core libraries. It seems that you have to create your own extension of `X509AsymmetricSecurityKey`  ,`X509SecurityToken`, `SecurityTokenProvider` and `ClientCredentialsSecurityTokenManager` like described in [How to: Change the Cryptographic Provider for an X.509 Certificate's Private Key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/change-cryptographic-provider-x509-certificate-private-key).

Answer (score 1):

Recently had same issue.  The OAuth2 library uses a different cryptography provider for one framework vs another.

[see line 30 here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth/OAuth2/ServiceAccountCredential.cs)

Our solution was to change our .dll from 4.61 to NetStandard.